# Change found text highlight in a Firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm developing an extension for Firefox which searches terms in a page. And I'd like to change found text highlight color and background. For example, I search for a letter "s" and by default it's selected with a blue rectangle with white text color. So I want to change the blue to the red.
How could I do this via JS?

### **Edit0:**

To select a found text I use `document.createRange()` and `selection.addRange()` methods.
I don't know how the default finder selects a found term and applies background to it.
So maybe the 'range' method is not the best.
But I think I'm searching a way to highlight this created range...

### **Edit1**:

Now I've partially resolved the color-changing preoblem. Just add a CSS rule with `::-moz-selection` and red background when a text is found and selected. Then for document 'onmousedown' I remove this rule not to leave the default selection as red.

But a new problem is when I find say a digit and it gets a selection the background of that selection is gray (so it looks like a text selection of an inactive window). Then when I click with my mouse somewhere in the document text and press F3 the extension finds the next digit and selects it with the red background. And next findings work right (with red background).

So my purpose is change that initial gray background to red.
Maybe I should change the inactive selection color...

### **Edit2:**

Now I updated my JS code:

```
var selection=w.getSelection()
var range=w.document.createRange()
range.setStart(foundNode,foundOffset)
range.setEnd(foundNode,foundOffset+foundLength)
selection.removeAllRanges()
selection.addRange(range)

var controller=gBrowser.docShell.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
               .getInterface(Ci.nsISelectionDisplay)
               .QueryInterface(Ci.nsISelectionController);

controller.setDisplaySelection(controller.SELECTION_ATTENTION)
controller.repaintSelection(controller.SELECTION_NORMAL)
```

Thanks to [Noitidart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1828637/noitidart)'s answer I found some information on how to use `nsISelectionController` XPCOM interface to select found text with background. Still I can't set a custom color for this background so that it be different from the default color of found text in Firefox. But setting the `ui.textSelectBackgroundAttention` preference in `about:config` to desired color will work with both my extension and default find engine.

I've found that `SELECTION_ATTENTION` constant is responsible for that background color and the `setDisplaySelection` method links the color to the selected text. But I couldn't find any implementation of this method. I saw only `nsISelectionController` idl file with its structure but no correspondent .cpp or .js file implementing this .idl. So I don't have information on how the color is set.

### **Edit3:**

Recently I added the "Highlight All" functionality to my extension. And a new question about color of this highlight has rised. Using the above tecnique will show all the matches with green find color (by default). But it's more comfortable to use a different color to distinguish the current match and others.

So I couldn't find another helpful `nsISelectionController` constant for the "Highlight All" selection. I simply set this selection to 'DISABLED' type and changed the `ui.textSelectBackgroundDisabled` `about:config` pref. This pref is obviously for the selected text background of an inactive window. And it worked for me.

`controller.setDisplaySelection(controller.SELECTION_DISABLED)`

Another thing is that I'm not sure that the `controller.repaintSelection()` in the previous Edit is necessary. I guess the selection didn't work without it when I started my experiments with this stuff. But now I removed that line and all still work.

### ***Plus:***

And some additional links if somebody will need:

> - [nsISelectionController Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsISelectionController)
> - [Selection Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)
> - [Forum question about highlight](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2662535)
> - [about:config prefs for highlight](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1013350-Changing-Highlight-Colors-in-FireFox)
> - [An Add-on using a similar tecnique](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hiliteonselection/)
> - [Finder.jsm and other sources](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/mozilla/firefox/toolkit/modules/Finder.jsm)

Also I used some files from Firefox source archive: [Firefox 33 Source](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/33.0/source/firefox-33.0.source.tar.bz2):

```
 - nsISelectionController.idl          [\content\base\public\]
 - nsTypeAheadFind.cpp                 [\toolkit\components\typeaheadfind\]
 - Finder.jsm                          [\toolkit\modules\]
 - findbar.xml                         [\toolkit\content\widgets\]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question to quicksilver via email and this is what he told me:

> You might find this one helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsISelectionController
>
> I'm hardly the master you think I am, actually. :) To change those colors I just change the values for preferences:
>
> `ui.textHighlightBackground`
>
> `ui.textHighlightForeground`
>
> `ui.textSelectBackgroundAttention` -> `SELECTION_ATTENTION`, it's not a highlight, it's a normal selection (as you would select some text with your mouse and it would turn the regular blue blackground, in windows at least) but it's given "attention", so it has the green background that the find operation reports. Basically it's a way of showing the user "Here I am!!" after firefox automatically selecs the text he searched for.
>
> And I really don't know most of those contants, SELECTION_NORMAL is for normal text selection, like it would be when you select text with your mouse, SELECTION_FIND is for the highlights, and I only know the ON/HIDDEN/OFF/DISABLED ones which are self-explanatory. SELECTION_SPELLCHECK is probably for the auto-correct when you are typing in an editable content node, but I'm just guessing that one from the name.
>
> Also, as far as I know, it's not possible to just create custom selection ranges/contants, as the code simply won't recognize them without editing the C++ code as well. Which is actually one of the reasons I haven't implemented https://github.com/Quicksaver/FindBar-Tweak/issues/76 yet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Now I guess the ui.textSelectBackgroundAttention preperty fits my problem. Cause I changed it to blue and my default found selection background changed to blue.

But now I need to find a way to change this property for my extension via JS.

Comment: Please read my edits. Maybe you could advise something for these.
And also I guess that nsISelectionController must help with changing the background but I can't figure out how to use it

Comment: Awesome edits thanks for sharing that code. I couldnt figure it out so you made more progress then me :)